# Command line - Why cant' I use the 'touch' command?

Tags: command-line, command, touch

I'm using [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-the-command-line/lessons/navigation/exercises/touch?action=lesson_resume&link_content_target=interstitial_lesson) to learn command-line. When I tried to use the command `touch file.txt`, it says,

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I searched on the forum and found out that I can use `echo.>file.txt`, and it worked.

I would like to know why the `touch` command doesn't work. Is this because I'm using Windows and not Mac? Can someone explain to me? Thanks!

This is the screenshot on my laptop......
[image]

Comment: You are using Windows command line not Shell. In Windows is no touch command available

Answer (score 4):

`touch` is not a command in the Windows shell, it is in the shells of Unix-like operating systems (Mac, Linux, etc) which provide derivatives of the original `sh` shell.

For Windows you can either use the workaround you found, or install a terminal emulator like **Cygwin**. In fact, Windows 10 is currently having a Linux environment being built in, meaning you could use it like Ubuntu, which will provide the right shell for `touch`.

Comment: Cygwin is not a terminal emulator. It includes a terminal `mintty` but it is much more than that. "Cygwin is:

    a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows." One of those tools is `touch`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, I almost mentioned others like Putty, but I wasn't quite sure whether they were 'just' terminal emulators. I've seen Cygwin mentioned so often to emulate `bash` that I'd forgotten it came with more than just that (I'm a Mac, Arch, Fedora user).

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this today as well, but on my case while trying Node.js. Yup, as they mentioned touch is for Unix. It seems most tutorials out there were created while using Macs. Anyway, I found another workaround, install touch via NPM...just make sure you are connected to the internet to download the package.

```
 C:\npm install touch-cli -g
```

I was able to use *touch* after.

Another issue I've encountered while working with Windows 10 is I cannot change to a different directory. If you encounter it as well while following the tutorials, try this instead of "cd ".

```
cd /D <directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

`cd` into the directory you want to create a file and type the following `type nul > filename.txt` this creates an empty file inside that directory.
and as per the question `touch` can't be used in windows 10 command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

**For a pseudo `touch` command using the methods above, create a file with this content:**

```
@echo off
type nul > %1
```

Name it `touch.bat` save it anywhere (**e.g.**, `C://` or `C://Users/YourUsername`), and add it to your PATH environment variable to use it as a native `touch` -like command.